# Django: Static files in subdirectory

Tags: python, css, django

I have static files like so

```
/static
  base.css
  /core
     /css
       style.css
     /js
       stuff.js
```

on localhost this works fine when i set href to /static/core/css/style.css for example
However when i deploy live i get an error when I try to visit that URL as Django seems to be trying to match it to a url pattern.

I really want to keep the subdirectories, how do i ensure that it treats all of them as static directories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that you need to configure your production server to serve static content for you. The development server serves static files by default as long as DEBUG = True, but on the live server you do NOT want Django to serve static content. Instead you want to front-end server (Apache or Nginx) to serve the files for you.

The Django docs are a good source for info on how to serve static content in production:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: this is not the problem...the problem is that subdirectories are not recognized. I am using gunicorn as a server.

Comment: If you get a URL pattern error then your front-end server is not configured properly to serve that file for you. For static content your Django app should not be involved AT ALL.

Comment: the point is that: static/style.css works fine, but static/css/style.css does not work... how do i make BOTH static/style.css AND static/css/style.css work?

Comment: Again, this is not a Django problem but a front-end problem. Your front-end server (Apache or Nginx) should catch all requests starting with /static/ and serve them directly, completely cutting Django out of the loop for static content.

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx (or something else) as front-end server? Update the question with the appropriate section from the config file and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: If I had 125 reputation I would downvote this. Pointing a user to the Django static files docs is so futile, those docs are so loose and not applicable to most use cases it's virtually pointless. That's why the user has come here asking about this!